# Do I assign the static IP address—as assigned by my ISP—to my DSL modem? If so, how?

Tags: modem, static-ip, dsl-modem

I’m a CenturyLink customer and today I added a static IP address to our account.

I’ve logged onto the DSL modem (an Actiontec C1000A DSL modem) and see that it has the IP address but I’m wondering if I have to assign the IP address to it?

I tried finding that information on the CenturyLink website, but couldn’t find it there. So do I have to assign the static IP address somewhere in my DSL modem’s configuration? And if so, where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I’ve logged onto the DSL modem (an Actiontec C1000A DSL modem) and see
>   that it has the IP address but I’m wondering if I have to assign the
>   IP address to it?

Pretty confident you don’t have to do anything else to use a static IP address as assigned by your ISP.

A static IP is typically associated with your physical connection—and perhaps even the actual MAC address from a device connected to that physical connection—so there would be no reason to do anything else with your DSL modem.

Remember: Your ISP controls the pool of addresses you received your static—and previous non-static—IP addresses from so they know who you are and what your connection is.

So if the static IP is there, you are solid.

Answer (score 2):

> I’m a CenturyLink customer and oday I added a static IP address to our account.
>
> I’ve logged onto the DSL modem (an Actiontec C1000A DSL modem) and see that it has the IP address but I’m wondering if I have to assign the IP address to it?

Technically, that means it's already assigned (and probably usable).

With most ISPs, the "static address" *does not* imply any sort of manual configuration sense – it is still assigned via the same automatic methods, i.e. either DHCP or PPP.

It's just static in the sense that it won't change. That is, the ISP's DHCP server has a "static lease" aka "reservation" configured for you, usually based on customer ID of some sort.

So at most, if the router still had an old address, you'd have needed to force it to obtain a new one – either by rebooting it, or using its 'release' menu item.

Comment: +1 - OK explanation, but there are plenty of ways to do this :)

Answer (score -1):

You can check your public IP by Googling "[Whasmyip](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=whatsmyip)."  Google will tell you your public IP right at the top of the page.

If the modem has the address, you are good to go.  However, you can always call CenturyLink for support and to ask questions...